# Connect ColdFusion to SQL Server database instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a SQL server (2008) database instance in ColdFusion 9 but there is no where to put an instance name in the CF administrator.  I can get in with .net using a connection string like so:

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

There is a place to enter a connection string in ColdFusion but I don't seem to be able to connect to the right instance (it seems to connect to the default instance).  Is there a way to connect ColdFusion to a SQL Server database instance in the administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are NOT using ColdFusion's sandbox security** then you can specify the instance name in the server field of the datasource definition in the ColdFusion administrator. As you mentioned, you would just specify `myServerName\myInstanceName`. But...

**If you are using ColdFusion's sandbox security** then that will not work.  I had this same issue when I upgraded to ColdFusion 9 and never did find a resolution.  I entered a bug at Adobe for it: [ColdFusion 9.0.1 Bug 84928](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3042666)  It has since been closed as "Deferred" with the reason "Not Enough Time".

I found that the connection issue arose when using ColdFusion's sandbox security. Disable it and the datasource will work with the instance name specified per above. Enable it and that same connection will fail.

In order to get around the bug you need to specify the database server only (without the instance name) in the server name field and specify the assigned port number for the named instance in the port number field.  See the bug for full details.

Comment: I was able to connect when I used the just the server name (no instance) in the Server field and the non-default port in port.  I still have the connection string with the instance name in the connection string field in advanced settings.  I'm not sure if this is needed or not.  Anyhow thanks!

Comment: The connection string should not be needed because you are specifying the settings in the other fields. (Assuming that you specified the username and password in the appropriate fields as well.) Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I have had no trouble with instances on 9.01 and 9.02

Comment: @JamesMohler - Are you using sandbox security? The bug only arises when sandbox security is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enter the Server with a \ and the name of the instance

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, this will work if you do NOT have sandbox security enabled in the ColdFusion administrator.

Comment: What was the error message. Also the error message should be a part of your question

Comment: @Miguel-F : I am running Win 2008 R2 64-bit. CF version is: 9,0,1,274733. ColdFusion was a clean install not an upgrade from 9.0 Sandbox is off.

Comment: @JamesMohler - _Sandbox is off_  That is why it works for you. With Sandbox on it will not work.  I updated my answer to try and clarify this better. If you have a dev server to test with you can verify. Just enable Sandbox security and "test" your datasource again. It will fail. Disable the sandbox and it will work again.  See the bug that I referenced for details. (Be sure to restart the ColdFusion service after enabling/disabling the sandbox feature.)

Comment: @Miguel-F : Yep, Sandbox security breaks it: Connection verification failed for data source: `EEMS
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The requested instance is either invalid or not running.`

Comment: Thanks for verifying. Not sure if this is still an issue in CF10 or not.